# Есть ли в Firebird 3 у пользователя ID?

Tags: база-данных, firebird

В Firebird 3 есть псевдо-таблица SEC$USERS в ней есть SEC$USER_NAME.

Где мне найти SEC$ID?

Мне нужно логировать действия пользователя,
мне бы хотелось:

```
INSERT INTO log (user_id, ...) VALUES (SEC$ID, ...);
```

а пока получается так:

```
INSERT INTO log (user_name, ...) VALUES (SEC$USER_NAME, ...);
```

С одной стороны хорошо что сразу видно пользователя,
а с другой 31 байт (CHAR) вместо 8 байт (BIGINT) немножко напрягает.

Comment: Собственно никто не запрещает создать в лог-базе таблицу юзеров, с синтетическим полем-счётчиком, и именно этот счётчик рисовать в лог. А при появлении нового юзера - добавлять его в эту таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

В всех существующих версиях Firebird ID пользователя имеет тип VARCHAR(31).

Текущее значение для логирования можно получить из системной переменной CURRENT_USER.

Сделано это по той причине, что список пользователей, которые могут логиниться зависит от настроек сервера, и в самой БД может не храниться.

Comment: Вы правы только отчасти, в новых версиях база данных может быть базой  данных безопасности для самой себя. Ссылка на документ в котором это описывается(страница 80, раздел "Размещение списка пользователей") https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZr6n1yunkAhVjposKHTIVAwsQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibase.ru%2Ffiles%2Ffirebird%2FFirebird3_SQL_features.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2lTx5ymhYAO8n2xABuXn36

Comment: Но при этом в новых же версиях CURRENT_USER может быть вообще из AD/LDAP, а не из security database

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE SEC$USERS ( SEC$USER_NAME   RDB$USER,
                         SEC$FIRST_NAME  SEC$NAME_PART, 
                         SEC$MIDDLE_NAME SEC$NAME_PART, 
                         SEC$LAST_NAME   SEC$NAME_PART, 
                         SEC$ACTIVE      RDB$BOOLEAN, 
                         SEC$ADMIN       RDB$BOOLEAN, 
                         SEC$DESCRIPTION RDB$DESCRIPTION
                      ) ;
```

Это всё, что есть в таблице... увы, `SEC$ID` там нет.

Comment: Это я заметил ;)